# How to Combine 2 query or create same query with join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries shown below and I'm trying to combine them into one in Access, can I do this using a join or another method?

Query 1

```
SELECT Table.ID, Sum Table.Amount as Complete_Total
FROM Table
WHERE Table.Status = "Complete"
GROUP BY Table.ID
```

Query 2

```
SELECT Table.ID, Sum Table.Amount as Failed_Total
FROM Table
WHERE Table.Status = "Failed"
GROUP BY Table.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try conditional sum.

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
Sum(IIF(t1.Status='Complete',t1.Amount,0)) AS [Complete Total], 
Sum(IIF(t1.Status='Failed',t1.Amount,0)) AS [Failed Total]
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.ID;
```

***Table data:***

[image]

***Query Output:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.ID
       Sum(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Complete' THEN Amount END) as Complete_Total,
       Sum(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Failed' THEN Amount END) as Failed_Total
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

In MS Access, this would be:

```
SELECT t.ID,
       Sum(IIF(t.Status = 'Complete', Amount, 0)) as Complete_Total,
       Sum(IIF(t.Status = 'Failed', Amount, 0)) as Failed_Total
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Comment: You have typo. There will be comma (,) after t.ID `SELECT t.ID, Sum(....`. Are you sure `CASE WHEN...` will work to MS-Access? I tried but it gives `Syntax error...`

Comment: @Harun24HR . . . I must've missed the MS Access tag when I answered.